# Positioning a textbox on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and it'll be a while till I get used to it. At the moment I'm trying to move a textbox around just to see how it works, but I can't really get it to move from the center. Tried using grid and it didn't move at all. Tried using pad x & y and it did move but in some places disappears. My goal is to make a simple log in screen.

This is what I got:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.messagebox

    #def logVali():


form = Tk()

form.title("Log in screen")

form.geometry("700x200+300+200")

txtVar = StringVar(None)

usrIn = Entry(form, textvariable = txtVar, width = 50)

usrIn.grid(row = 30, column = 40)

usrIn.pack()

form.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you want it moved (left, right, top, top-right, etc.)?  Or do you want it moved to a specific pair of x and y coordinates?

Comment: Yeah, I want it moved to a specific coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your box probably isn't moving as you are using .grid *and* .pack

Depending on what you want, you could use either the .grid , .pack , or .place functions. You've already seen grid. And pack and place work like so:

```
.place(x=10,y=30) #replace values with required
```

This works for positioning absolutely, however it falls down when you come to resize the window. If a user dragged the window bigger; the box would stay in the position you set. In other words, the coordinates are not relative to the size of the window.

You have already used .pack , however you used it strangely so I'll explain.

```
.pack()
```

This will place the box in the centre, and the next item you use .pack() for will place it underneath the last. This is useful for making sure nothing overlaps, but it's not always practical and/or good looking.

One last word of warning; all of these three functions return None. That means that it you intend to edit the boxes in anyway: call the function seperatly.

```
#Some tutorials will say....
Button1 = Button(text="foo",command=bar).pack()

#However you should do this...
Button1 = Button(text="foo,command=bar)
Button1.pack()
```

Comment: I didn't know that about pack. I thought it was like necessary. Nice to know that kind of information. Thanks

Comment: When you say "This will place the box in the centre", that is not correct. The default is to place it at the top of the container. It will be centered horizontally, but at the top of the window. Personally, I describe pack as best for organization of single rows or columns of data (eg: toolbars, or toolbar, main area, and statusbar top-to-bottom).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *put something in the center* you should use `place` not `pack` nor `grid`:

```
from Tkinter import *

form = Tk()
form.title("Log in screen")
form.geometry("700x200+300+200")


label = Label(form, text='User:')
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='s')

txtVar = StringVar(None)
usrIn = Entry(form, textvariable = txtVar, width = 50)
usrIn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='n')

form.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, you can do it with grid, too. Row 1, column 1, then give a weight of 1 to row and column 0 and 2. Still, if you genuinely need a widget at the center of another widget, place is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Yes, you have a point, always are more than one way of doing things :)